# Trying to create reusable custom ajax form plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

**Updated code - working**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.mbajaxform = function( mbopts ) {

        var mb_form_items       = $(this).find('input, submit, button'),
            mb_form_type        = mb_mbtheme_js[0],
            mb_get_page_slug    = mb_mbtheme_js[1],
            mb_redirect         = mb_mbtheme_js[2],
            mb_redirect_time    = mb_mbtheme_js[3],
            mb_form_disable     = mb_mbtheme_js[4];

        // create the defaults
        let mbdefaults = {
                beforeSend: function( el, beforeSend ) {
                            },

                success:    function( el, success ) {
                            },

                complete:   function( el, complete ) {
                            },

                error:      function( el, error ) {
                            }
        };


        // extend the defaults
        let mboptions = $.extend( {}, mbdefaults, mbopts );

        return this.each( function() {

            // the variable for this
            var $this = $(this);

            function beforesend_callback(e) {
                mboptions.beforeSend( $this, e );
            }

            function success_callback(e) {
                mboptions.success( $this, e );
            }

            function complete_callback(e) {
                mboptions.complete( $this, e );
            }

            function error_callback(e) {
                mboptions.error( $this, e );
            }


            // run the function
            $this.on( mb_form_type, function(mb) {

                // stop the default function of buttons
                mb.preventDefault();

                var mb_ajax_form_data = new FormData( $this[0] );

                // do the ajax
                $.ajax({
                    method:         "POST",
                    data:            mb_ajax_form_data,
                    contentType:    false,
                    processData:    false,
                    beforeSend:     beforesend_callback,
                    success:        success_callback,
                    complete:       complete_callback,
                    error:          error_callback
                });
            });

        });
    };
}( jQuery ));


$("#mbform").mbajaxform();
```

---

**Original question**

This is my first attempt at creating a plugin but was following a few tutorials hoping it would work first go - rookie!

I have an AJAX form that I noticed was being repeated (such as password resets, theme settings, user creation) across a few sub-sites within my network (using Wordpress Multisite), so I decided it could be more beneficial to create a function that was able to be extended (if changes needed) but otherwise apply the defaults.

> *see edit revisions for older code*

Comment: Preventing the default action of button clicks doesn't prevent a form being submitted. You have to listen the submit event of the form and prevent its default action instead.

Comment: @Teemu when I run the script outside of being a plugin the preventDefault works

Comment: Turns out I had a few things causing issues: 1. the placement of the js file wasn't correct, 2. calling the default variables within another default variable, some naming - I have updated the question to have the working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance looks like you might not be referencing the correct options variable.

You're setting it with the name `mboptions`

```
 let mboptions = $.extend({}, mbdefaults, mbopts);
```

but then trying to access it using `options`

```
options.beforeSend($this, e);
```

And when you're trying to bind the submit event you're not accessing the event name from the options object. So instead of

```
$this[mb_form_type](function(mb) {...});
```

I think

```
$this.on(mboptions.mb_form_type, function(mb) {...}):
```

is a bit more readable (also you can later remove the binding with `this.off(mboptions.mb_form_type)` if you need to ;)

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't notice as I was copying and pasting. Still not working though

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console? You'll need to turn preserve log on to see the messages after the page posts

Comment: No errors, as far as I can tell, anything after `return this.each(function() {`

Comment: A couple more things from reading your code, the variable `mb_ajax_form_links` is declared inside the form submit handler, but you are trying to access it inside other functions so it will be out of scope for them. Since you are looking for the interactive elements inside your form I think you could replace `$(mb_ajax_form_links)` with `el.find('input, select, button')`

Comment: Also you don't want to execute the functions in your ajax parameters object, you just need to reference them so instead of `beforeSend: beforesend_callback(),` you need `beforeSend: beforesend_callback,` etc